# (Pure FTP) FTP User login directory

Tags: ftp

I've installed Open Panel, which seems to ship with Pure FTP server. I added a linux user ftpuser, and now I can log in with it. I'd like to specify a directory to which this user starts with when it logs in.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a program like `usermod` with its `-d` option if you have that installed:

```
 usermod -d /new/ftpuserhome ftpuser
```

if you don't have that, you can also edit the `/etc/passwd` file as `root` and change the 6th field (the one before the last field (`:` is the field separator).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did this in fact, but I thought that I don't have to specify a home directory as a directory where ftp connection leads a user to when initializated (i.e. I thought there is possibility for different home dir e.g. when logged in to the shell, and ftp starting dir)?

Comment: @forsberg AFAIK there is for virtual users only (there has to be of course), but since you indicated the **linux user ftpuser**, IMO this is the solution. I don't know what happens if you specify both, but I assume the virtual user info would prevail. That might however become an update nightmare if you forget to sync passwords between `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/pureftpd.passwd`, as there is no fall-through mode for looking up information.